# Special Symbols in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding

I was using Eclipse, & i had no this Problem :

```
IllegalDataException: Unable to serialize FindRecents state: The data "�" is not legal for a JDOM character content: Surrogate Pair Truncated.
```

I am trying to copy a Special Character :

When i copy it, Android Studio put : \uD83C\uDFA7

I have tried to set the project/file encoding to utf-8 but this does not change nothing,

How i can Correctly use this Character in Android Studio ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly convert from the Unicode value of the Emoji to make it into a String.

You can easily do this as follows:

```
//U+1F3A7 is the Unicode value of the Headphone emoji
int headPhoneEmoji = 0x1F3A7;

//Convert to string
String headPhoneString = new String(Character.toChars(headPhoneEmoji));

//Display it
myTextBox.setText(headPhoneString);
```